# Magento2 Credit memo error: "We found an invalid quantity to refund item"

Tags: magento2, creditmemo

When I tried to create credit memo of even simple product, it gives me errror message "We found an invalid quantity to refund item "product_name".". I am not managing stock in my website. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

it means qty ordered not match with qty invoiced, run following query to resolve the issue

```
update `sales_order_item`
set qty_invoiced = qty_ordered
WHERE `order_id` = ORDER_ID
```